# Using popen in windows C program

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I am using QtCreator with C++. I included the libraries #include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h> but when I use the function popen it gives an error - 
`No matching function for call to _popen` This is the code I am using :

```
FILE *pf;
       char ch;
       pf = popen(ui->command->text(), "r");
       while ((ch = fgetc(pf)) != EOF)
           putchar(ch);
```

What could be the reason for this? Is it because I am working on windows? Any ideas on how to resolve it?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details. What type of application do you want to create? What compiler do you use? Copy&paste the compile/link command that gets executed and the complete error message. See also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/popen-wpopen?view=msvc-160

Comment: Yeah it's the problem with text function as the open expects a char * and I am passing a Qstring. changing to `ui->command->text().toStdString().c_str()` worked

Comment: If you use Qt and specifically use `ui->command->text()` then it's C++ for sure. It's legal to use C functions in C++. Parts of the standard C functions are adopted in the C++ standard API. AFAIK, system functions (C API) can be used in C++ as well. However, it's still a C++ program. (C and C++ are two distinct languages.)

Comment: Also, if you are using QT and dealing with files, [consider using QFile](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfile.html). It will use the Q style datatypes and can provide additional file I/O functionality.